TeXstudio arara magic comment is not recognized
Why does the following document
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: lualatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Hello
\end{document}

return this message

%!TeX program not recognized! (txs:///arara). Using default.

despite having arara installed on my Win11 PC

and defining the user command arara in TeXstudio 4.7.3?


Try %.tex instead.

@Sigur on mac, it works without the file type.

On my win10 machine it works if I use "Build and View" but I get the same message as you if I just click "Compile"

I found out it works if I use Build and View (as suggested by @mbert) or set the Default Compiler value to txs:///arara without using the magic comment % !TeX program = txs:///arara.

